VBA filter pivot table with wildcard array from named range
I'm currently struggling to get a dynamic filter to work.
Initial situation: Pivot Table where i need to filter for multiple different words.
It is always build like this:
7.06610.14.0 EDR-E -> i need to filter for some specific words
7.03083.11.0 EAM
7.05569.18.0 REGELKLAPPE
7.09451.00.0 EAM-S
...
I created a named range for the words i need to filter.
I'm able to get all of them in an array with a wildcard character, but the system just won't filter.
Here's the code to fill my array:
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim myNr As Long

Bereich = Range("_Bereich") 'Named range
myArray = Range("_" & Bereich & "Filter") 
For myNr = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)
    myArray(myNr, 1) = "*" & myArray(myNr, 1)
Next myNr

That's the output:
Array input
But here all my tries failed...
i just can't get these to be filtered on my pivot table.
These are just a few of the options i tried:
Sub test2()
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim myNr As Long
Dim pvItem As PivotItem

Bereich = Range("_Bereich")

myArray = Range("_" & Bereich & "Filter")
For myNr = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)
    myArray(myNr, 1) = "*" & myArray(myNr, 1)
    Debug.Print myArray(myNr, 1)
Next myNr

Worksheets(Bereich).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("tblMenge" & Bereich).PivotFields("Material")
    .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    .ClearAllFilters
    For Each pvItem In .PivotItems
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(pvItem.Caption, myArray, 0)) Then
            pvItem.Visible = True
        Else
            pvItem.Visible = False
        End If
    Next pvItem
End With

End Sub

Sub test3()
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim myNr As Long
Dim pvItem

Bereich = Range("_Bereich")
Worksheets(Bereich).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("tblMenge" & Bereich).PivotFields("Material")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    For Each pvItem In .PivotItems("All")
        pvItem.Visible = False
    Next
    
    myArray = Range("_" & Bereich & "Filter") 
    
    For myNr = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)
        .PivotItems(myArray(myNr, 1)).Visible = True
    Next myNr
End With

End Sub

Sub test5()
Bereich = Range("_Bereich")

Dim myArray As Variant
myArray = Range("_" & Bereich & "Filter")

Dim pvFld As PivotField, found As Boolean, n As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Set pvFld = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("tblMenge" & Bereich).PivotFields("Material")

With pvFld
    .ClearAllFilters
    For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
        found = False
        For j = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)
        myArray(j, 1) = "*" & myArray(j, 1)
            If .PivotItems(i).Name = myArray(j, 1) Then
                found = True
                n = n + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If i = .PivotItems.Count And n = 0 Then
            .ClearAllFilters
            MsgBox "Unable to filter by the list of pivot items", _
                vbExclamation, "No items found"
        ElseIf Not found Then
            .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
        End If
    Next i
    .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
End With

End Sub


In what way did your attempted code fail?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


PivotItemName in .PivotItems(...) muse be exactly same as the item. It doesn't support wildcards.

Like is an operator to compare two strings. It supports wildcards.


Microsoft documentation:

Like operator

Sub test3()
    Dim myArray() As Variant
    Dim myNr As Long
    Dim pvItem As PivotItem
    Worksheets(Bereich).Select
    Bereich = Range("_Bereich")
    myArray = Range("_" & Bereich & "Filter").Value
    For myNr = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)
        myArray(myNr, 1) = "*" & myArray(myNr, 1)
    Next myNr
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("tblMenge" & Bereich).PivotFields("Material")
        .ClearAllFilters
        .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
        For Each pvItem In .PivotItems
            pvItem.Visible = False
            For myNr = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 1)
                If pvItem.Name Like myArray(myNr, 1) Then
                    pvItem.Visible = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next myNr
        Next
    End With
End Sub

